# C++ : Structs, operator "new", and const

Tags: c++, struct, constants, new-operator

I'm going to be speaking in hypotheticals because I haven't tested anything as of yet. I'm not even sure where to begin.

So I have a few structs that I initialized with values and I want them to be passed to a class. But I want each instance of the class to have their own instance of one of those structs initially defined with the same values.

For the sake of visualization:

```
struct Car{
int value, mileage,

std::string model_name;
std::string owner;

double insurance_premium} 

Car Porsche, Toyota, Honda;
```

How would I, or is it even possible to, create new instances of any of those declared `Car`s? Can you do a copy constructor for structs?

I had an idea to maybe declare and initialize each of the `Car` objects, then label them as `const`. Then maybe call `new` on them. Would that just implode my everything? I don't know.

Assistance please.

Comment: Default copy and assignment should work for this, ie `Car newCar = Porsche;`

Comment: You already have a compiler-defined default copy constructor (and assignment operator) which does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ there is no difference between a `class` and a `struct` except that `struct` defaults its members to `public` and `class` defaults to `private`.  Anything else you can do to one you can do to the other.

Comment: So, I could just defined a copy constructor and just create identical versions of the same struct?

Comment: You could.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @neutralboolean: The C++ compiler will automatically create a copy constructor - no need to define one yourself.

Comment: I want to define an object of `Car`, e.g. "Object1", and then be able to create another object that has the same member values as Object1 without having to just manually initialize with the same values.

Comment: @neutralboolean: That is exactly what a copy constructor does. And if you use compiler-managed types and let the compiler generate a default copy constructor for you, you get all this functionality for free, you don't have to write any code for it.  Just assign one object instance to another and let the compiler handle the rest.